# Conservation of Energy/Momentum and Relativistic Gravity

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, conservation-laws

This question revolves around a thought experiment where 6 equal masses are arranged at the points of a regular hexagon with the exact velocity to put them all in a circular orbit in the same direction around the centre of mass (this is to help keep the maths simple).

My understanding of relativistic gravity may be wrong but I'm assuming that the effects of gravity are "transmitted" through space at the speed of light and so the attraction one mass experiences depends on where another mass was some time ago, not where it is in that instant.

So in our 6 mass system, each mass will be approaching the location of the mass in front and receding from the location of the mass behind. Since the time/distance the gravitational effect reaches a mass from the one in front will be smaller than the time/distance from the one behind, you would expect each mass to be attracted to the mass in front of it. This would cause each mass to accelerate thus violating conservation of momentum, angular momentum and energy.

Where is the flaw in this experiment?

Apologies if this has been asked before - I searched but couldn't find anything similar.